# Github pages with polymer

Tags: git, github, build, polymer

## Context

Polymer-cli 0.17.0

Git 2.10.2

## Problem

I have a polymer project, but I have to put my builded files in the `gh-pages` branch.

Before, my solution was to use git worktree and use the `build/bundled/` directory as the `gh-pages` directory. But when I updated from polymer `0.16.0` to `0.17.0` it started deleting the `build/` directory before building, so the `.git` file is removed, thus losing my git worktree configuration for `gh-pages`.

Right now I'm manually moving my files from my `master` branch on `build/bundled` to my `gh-pages` branch on root.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you create a shell script that calls `polymer build` and then copies the `.git` file into `build/bundled`?

Comment: Yes I can, the `.git` file is quite simple. But I was hoping for something that  worked on both Windows and Linux. Still a nice solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This solution](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) is nice. It looks like you'd have to stop ignoring the build folder though (I think it's good practice to keep builds separate from the source, but doesn't matter too much).

Another option would be to use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to build your project, it wouldn't be too hard to preserve the `.git` files across builds. Here is [my gulpfile](https://gist.github.com/stephentuso/8f25563fd473cbb07c79f82d320d41b2), I have a weird structure for my app though and you'd have to do some editing for that to work. I haven't used it, but [polymer-build](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build) might be useful.

Also, did you mean Polymer 1.7.0?

Comment: Sorry, it was the polymer-cli, not polymer, that was version `0.17.0`, fixed.
I liked a lot the subtree solution! But I will give gulp a try, thank you for all the options and for giving your code as an example :)